# Div is not positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a really simple layout for an introduction to web design for a club I'm visiting, and, ironically, I can't get it to work. I've been trying and trying and I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious.
Here's the code:

```
<head>
<title>Scooby-Doo on Zombie Island
</title>
<style>
body {
background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-O-EF2xvEtxQ/TYwND_eHYpI/AAAAAAAAAY8/_pkalo1cASU/s1600/vlcsnap-2011-03-24-23h31m32s96.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
p {
color: #fff;
}
#scooby-title {
margin-left: 325px;
margin-top: -10px;
max-width: 400px;
height: auto;
-webkit-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2.5deg);
    transform: rotate(2.5deg);
}
#real {
top: 20px;
right: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/13151/hdmovielogo/scooby-doo-on-zombie-island-5223b1ea2a286.png" id="scooby-title" />
<div id="real">
<p>"This time, the monsters are real"</p>
</div>
</body>
```

For whatever reason, the div "real" will not budge. Help?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Sorry: next time I will actually say what I need help with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#real {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgot to set the position css

```
#real {
  position:absolute;
  top: 140px;
  right: 90px;
}
```

Here a JSFiddle to help you out..

http://jsfiddle.net/DGN6N/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your post what you are trying to do exactly with the text.

I would use the margin property it essentially clears the space around an element as well as positions it.

```
#real {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Pro tip:  You can also combine these into one property to make it easier.

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```

In your case:

```
margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
```

Please be more specific if you are looking to float or center the text vertically/horizontally additional markup is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to center align the #real div. Simply do it like

```
#real {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```